# Optimized Project Structure in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I'm in a c++ project on linux in the starting stages. (team contains 3-5 developer, IDE is Eclipse CDT 6) And i'm wondering your ideas about what should be the project structure about the following subjects:

- Dependency management, how would you reference different sub-project directories in the same project
- Building system, handwrite makefile or Eclipse automake? (Eclipse generates makefiles for per project. and i want a general makefile for all the subprojects)
- For A Test framework, would i prefer precompiled library or holding the source of framework on the project, then building with the overall building process?

> Sample sub-projects
>
> - /Project.Model.A
> - /Project.Model.B
> - /Project.Model.A.Tests
> - /Project.Model.B.Tests
> - /Project.Views etc...

And i'm looking for an open source project similar to this structure...

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poco framework is suitable

Answer (score 1):

For a great look of **huge** C++ project with tons of nested autogenerated Makefiles, I suggest you to check QT 4 sources. It's amazing how them reached a very solid and reliable structure with that number of subprojects and dependencies. It's true, anyway, that they use QMake (own tool) for handling .pro (project definitions) and .pri (project include) files.

Recently I worked with **CMake build system** and I have to say that's very handly, driving you to split sources from binaries by design and with overall good tools for configuring your compiler's options. I know that should be compatible with Eclipse, check [here](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse) for details. It will enable also graphic configure and make tool within Eclipse framework.